# Typescript: Declare function that returns a nested array

Tags: arrays, typescript, return

I'm declaring a function in typescript that returns a nested array, but i'm unsure on how to declare the return type and declare the array that gets returned. Can anyone help? Here's what I have

```
myFunction(items: any): [] {
  const data = [];
  for (const item of items) {
    data.push([item.parameter1, item.parameter2])
  }
  return data; // IDE throws error here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `myFunction(): any[][]`:

An example:

```
myFunction(): any[][] {
    let data = [,];
    data = [[1], [2], [3]];
    console.log(data);
    return data; 
}
```

[A stackblitz example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-example-qxcc3m?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @MichaelRennison I am glad that it helped to you!:)

Answer (score 1):

As we work with static type system, the more correct way would be to specify something more than `any`. Consider such type safe version:

```
type Item = {
    parameter1: any; // here better some type 
    parameter2: any; // here better some type 
}

type ParametersTupleArr = [Item['parameter1'], Item['parameter2']][]; // return type
function myFunction(items: Item[]): ParametersTupleArr {
  const data = [] as ParametersTupleArr;
  for (const item of items) {
    data.push([item.parameter1, item.parameter2])
  }
  return data;
}
```

Type `[Item['parameter1'], Item['parameter2']][]` says that we will output array of 2-element tuples with types of parameters of `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution if some type safety is needed:

```ts
interface Item<P1, P2> {
  parameter1: P1; 
  parameter2: P2; 
}

function myFunction<P1, P2>(items: Item<P1,P2>[]) {

  const data: [Item<P1, P2>['parameter1'], Item<P1, P2>['parameter2']][] = [];

  for (const item of items) {
    data.push([item.parameter1, item.parameter2])
  }

  return data; // returns [P1, P2][]

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYB4AKBGAGmRwCYA+ZAbwChlkAHOKODCSKPALmLwG5laDJizbQS3Uv2oBfatRgBXEAjDAA9iGQYAngDElK9SFyFi5ABTBMAZ27oI2fAVJkA2gF0AlFTl0EG6zBkABM4MDhuV3tHUxdXAHJGZlZ2PHj3ImiTIjjE4RSxdPcPZABeZA9eX2QYNShkc38QQOQrB2Q1GFabbxo6OlDwgDp6BWsAC3NXNowR-NEOIhm55IWSL0FZQSg2BShNQbh+AHpj5B2wPeaKpzNi9zlpIA)